# Multidimensional Array PHP from Database Result With Same ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

How to store data from MySQL to a multidimensional array in PHP? This ini My database [My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU6mM.jpg)

I want to store every this database to multidimensional array like this

`tId    = array('Bid'=>'Brg', 'Bid'=>'Brg', 'Bid'=>'Brg');`

i have this this code but its doesnt work

```
 $this->db->query($query);
    $transactions = array();
    while($row=$this->db->fetchAll()){
        $transactionId = $row['id'];
        $productId = $row['produk_id'];
        $product = $row['produk'];
       $transactions[$transactionId]=array($productId, $product);
    }
```

Comment: How many iterations do you expect `fetchAll()` to make?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @YourCommonSense has a tidy menu to peruse: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE

Comment: Try this.
$data = array();
            while($row=$this->db->fetchAll()){
                $transactionId  = $row['id'];
                $productId      = $row['produk_id'];
                $product        = $row['produk'];
               $transactions[$transactionId]=array($productId, $product);
               array_push($data,$transactions);
            }

Comment: @mickmackusa I expect 10 iterations

Comment: `fetchAll()` only provides 1  ... "All"

Comment: @mickmackusa i have 2 function in core, fetchAll and fetch. fetchAll() with return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and fetch() with return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); so what must i make to make iteration for every Brg in sama Tid?

Comment: You can loop with `fetch()` and manually construct the desired output array, but PDO offers some awesome techniques (as shown in my duplicate link and the link to phpdelusions).  Please take a moment to actually read what I have directed you to.  Closing your question is not a punishment, I am referring you to excellent pre-existing resources.